# Using jQuery (and perhaps CSS), how do I hide an element without collapse and animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide

The following is the desired span which will be hidden

```
<span class="lastSave" name="lastSave">Last Saved by <i name="lastSavedBy"></i> at <i name="lastSaved"></i> </span>
```

There is a table below this in the page.

The following is the relevant functions in the javascript invoked at some event.
Note that this one makes the table move up.

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').hide();
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').show();
}
```

In replace of the above snippets in the javascript, I tried the following. This does not make the table move up. But this one has some kind of fading out which is not desired in my application.

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').animate({opacity:0});
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').animate({opacity:100});
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get it to disapeer but not move any of the surrounding elements? Do you want this to be done with animation or without? This is not very clear...

Comment: The clue is in the name. animate() well, it animates.
You could try using css() instead of animate.
I recommend using visibility, set to 'hidden' or 'visible' as appropriate, if you want to keep everything spaced out the same way.

Answer (score 6):

Well I wanted everything else to stay in place, so the `.hide()` in jQuery didn't work because this is equivalent to adding the following class in CSS

```
.hide{
display: none
}
```

Also, I didn't want any form of animation so the `.animate()` and changing the opacity from 0 to 1 isn't what I am looking for. I have tried it and I can see the element fade out. I want it to disappear instantly without all the others in the page move.

I decided to use the .css( propertyName, value  )

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('visibility','hidden');
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('visibility','visible');
}
```

which is the shorter way of adding a class like this one:

```
.hider{
visibility: hidden
}
```

to the element using

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    $(' [name="lastSave"]').addClass('hider');
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    $(' [name="lastSave"]').removeClass('hider');
}
```

similar to what Jamie Dixon suggests.

I have not tried what Nightw0rk suggests:

```
function hideLastSaved(){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('opacity','0');
}

function showLastSaved(){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('opacity','1');
}
```

but will try it just so I know how it looks like.

Thank you all very much for your brilliant suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

The hide method changes the `display` property of the element to `none`.

If you want to keep the elements position whilst hidding it, add a class that sets `visibility` to `hidden`.

**CSS:**

```
.hider{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    $(' [name="lastSave"]').addClass('hider');
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    $(' [name="lastSave"]').removeClass('hider');
}
```

Here's a very basic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dWw7F/

Answer (score 2):

Try changinging the css visible property.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideLastSaved(){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('opacity','0');
}

function showLastSaved(){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('opacity','1');
}
```

Comment: My mistake, the OP didn't specify that he wants the element to take up no space when hidden, your answer is fine.

Although I've seen IE have issues with opacity. (Along with everything else)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to change the visibility of the `span`:

```
$('#uniqueSpanId').animate({opacity: 0.0});
```

This will change the opacity of a span with `uniqueSpanId` to 0 making it invisible. Changing it back from that is simple doing the opposite command:

```
$('#uniqueSpanId').animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('display','none');
}

function showLastSaved(form){
    jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').css('display','block');
}
```

`jQuery hide()` = set `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`, with a transition

`jQuery show()` = set `display: block` and `visibility: visible`, with a transition

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the older versions of JQuery then use the following:

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').fadeOut(1);
}

function showLastSaved(form){
jQuery(' [name="lastSave"]').fadeIn(1);
}
```

The "1" simply sets a time scale of 1 millisecond which is technically nothing and if you are using the newer versions of JQuery then just add $ instead of JQuery:

```
function hideLastSaved(form){
$('[name="lastSave"]').fadeOut(1);
}

function showLastSaved(form){
$('[name="lastSave"]').fadeIn(1);
}
```